# [[NSManagedObject changedValuesForCurrentEvent]] return old values

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

[NSManagedObject changedValuesForCurrentEvent] return old values. Anybody faced this problem?

Docs says:

> Returns a dictionary containing the keys and (new) values of persistent properties that have changed since the last posting of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.

But in real it return old values.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when responding to the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.  I don't know if this is consistent with the other `NSManagedObjectContext` notifications.  As a work around, I use the keys to grab the new values from the managed object itself via:

```
NSDictionary *changedProperties = [managedObject changedValuesForCurrentEvent];
for(NSString *key in changedProperties) {
    NSObject *newValue = [managedObject performeSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)];
}
```

On the flip side: I've found (in certain circumstances), you have to un-fault your objects to get the current/old values before the save operation takes place using `[managedObjectContext refreshObj:managedObject mergeChanges:NO]`.  In my case, I needed to traverse the relationships of deleted objects.  But the soon-to-be-deleted object relationships were already nulled out.  Refreshing the object solved this.

Hope this helps.